# How to get Html post request value in Controller?

Tags: magento2.3, php, controllers, phtml, html

I've been trying to send the SKU of the product from the product page to another page so I can integrate it with an API.

Here's my code phtml code:
[image: PHTML Code]

Here's my Controller code:

[image: Controller]

For some reason I can't seem to get my SKU across so I can receive it on the other side? can someone please enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. ignore comments and naming, I remove the former and change the latter later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you did well.

As per Magento coding following are the 2 way to get post value.

1. $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('monkey');
2. $this->getRequest()->getPost('monkey');

Please check both the way and let me know if any.

If this helps to build your login then hit like.

Enjoy your coding!!! :)

Hiren Patel